# statements and return within a lambda expression lambda

Tags: c#, linq, if-statement, lambda, conditional-statements

In C# I'm trying to verify if a buss full of passengers is ready to go by verifying the passengers payments:

```
bool busReadyToGo = true;
passengers.Any(p => p.paymentStatus == PaymentRegistryEnum.NotPaid ?  busReadyToGo = false; return busReadyToGo; : continue; );
```

So this should check all the passengers payment status, if it encounters `one` passenger that hasn't paid then it stops right there and returns busReadytoGo = false. otherwise it continues iterating/filtering passengers, which means it will later return true if a passenger hasn't paid.

Not sure if this is the right way to do this within the Linq/lambda expression, because I keep getting syntax errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any already stops its enumeration when it meets the first element that returns true in the lambda expression. You just need to get the result from Any

```
busReadyToGo = !passengers.Any(p => p.paymentStatus == PaymentRegistryEnum.NotPaid);
```

If you look at the [Remarks section in docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Any__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__) you can read

> The enumeration of source is stopped as soon as the result can be
>   determined.

Comment: What does it return? a bool? Do I need to handle null?

Comment: Yes, it returns a bool, No there is no null to handle here

Comment: even if I pass an empty List?

Comment: Yes, if you use an empty list then the result will be false

Answer (score 2):

The method .Any will already return a bool value. There is no need to include an if-Statement in the expression.
This should do just fine:

```
bool busReadyToGo = !passengers.Any(p => p.paymentStatus == PaymentRegistryEnum.NotPaid)
```